# Display tab title as 'blog tagline | blog title'

Tags: php, theme-development, title, customization, wp-title

I am currently displaying my title liek this `<?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?>` it works fine for every page besides home page where tab currently says `Blog title | Blog tagline` is there a way I can change it to `Blog tagline | Blog title` ? Without affecting other pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can include a check for `is_home()` or `is_front_page()` and return a different title based on that.

**Update:** [TwentyEleven does it like this for example (lines 27 to 45).](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/header.php)